# How to make an existing website responsive using zengrids?

Tags: 7, theming, navigation

i'm creating a website using drupal 7, `zen theme` with some other modules, like `superfish menu` for example, for now the website is empty, i'm wondering how to make the website responsive from now ? Can i just (from my starterkit theme) access to the css (or create my own) that contains some media queries and it will work ? or `zengrids` is a best solution ?

Comment: You can also use other responsive grid systems:  [Can Susy function as a swappable layout for Zen 7.5?](https://www.drupal.org/node/1727530)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the [Superfish module](https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish) plays well with the [Zen theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/zen). By default, it will toggle wide dropdown menus to accordion style menus at 768px.

The superfish library includes sass and css template files you can drop into your theme's scss or css folders.

I am using a custom theme based on Zen 7x-6x starterkit.